# How to replace cross browser javascript to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code I have written - javascript code for IE and Chrome.

How can replace this with jQuery?

All this code working fine with the Javascript but I want replace it with jQuery.

Please help me to resolve this issue

```
  function GetObject(objName)
    {
        var objReturn;      
        if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
        {
           var x = top.document.forms.Form1.ownerDocument.getElementById("iframe_module_details");
        var y = (x.contentWindow || x.contentDocument);

            if (y.document && y.document.getElementById(objName))
                return y.document.getElementById(objName)

            if (window.Form1 && window.Form1.document.getElementById(objName)) {                
            objReturn = window.Form1.document.getElementById(objName);
        }


            else if (window.parent.document.forms[0].document.getElementById(objName)) 
        {
            objReturn = window.parent.document.forms[0].document.getElementById(objName);
        }
            else if (top.frames[0].document.forms[0].document.getElementById(objName)) 
        {
            objReturn = top.frames[0].document.forms[0].document.getElementById(objName);
        }
            else if (window.parent && window.parent.Form1 && window.parent.Form1.document.getElementById(objName)) {                
            objReturn = window.parent.Form1.document.getElementById(objName);
            }

            else if (opener) {              
                if (opener.opener) {
                    if (opener.opener.parent.Form1 && opener.opener.parent.Form1.document.getElementById(objName)) {
                        objReturn = opener.opener.parent.Form1.document.getElementById(objName);
                    }
                }
                else if (opener.parent && opener.parent.Form1 && opener.parent.Form1.document.getElementById(objName)) {
                    objReturn = opener.parent.Form1.document.getElementById(objName);
                }
            }
        }
        else { //For Chrome         

            if (window.Form1 && window.Form1.document.getElementById(objName)) {                
                objReturn = window.Form1.document.getElementById(objName);
        }
            else if (document.getElementById(objName)) 
        {
                objReturn = window.parent.document.forms[0].document.getElementById(objName);
            }

            else if (document.getElementById(objName)) 
            {
                objReturn = top.frames[0].document.forms[0].document.getElementById(objName);
            }
            else if (window.parent && window.parent.Form1 && window.parent.Form1.document.getElementById(objName)) {                
                objReturn = window.parent.Form1.document.getElementById(objName);
            }
            else if (opener) {              
                if (opener.opener) {
                    if (opener.opener.parent.Form1 && opener.opener.parent.Form1.document.getElementById(objName)) {
                    objReturn = opener.opener.parent.Form1.document.getElementById(objName);
                }           
            }
                else if (opener.parent && opener.parent.Form1 && opener.parent.Form1.document.getElementById(objName)) {
                objReturn = opener.parent.Form1.document.getElementById(objName);
                }
            }
        }
        //alert(objReturn);

        return objReturn;
    }
```

I don't want multiple code for different browser

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very big for this simple task. 
If I read correctly your code, it seems to always use getElementById, so it's very easy with jQuery.

So you can replace all this code with this function :

```
function GetObject(objName) {
    return $('#'+objName).get(0); // Return the DOM element of objName, same as document.getElementById(objName)
}
```